# sReceiving: "Unrecognized alias: proxy.sessionStorage" after Build

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I did my project Build and I´m receiving an error, my app is not recognizing the session stores.

```
  proxy: {
    type: 'sessionstorage',
    id: 'sessionTimeline',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      rootProperty: 'query'
    }
  }
```

When I change the type to "memory" my code works fine, but the type must be sessionstorage because I want to keep all the data from my store saved when I refresh my page.

> Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias:
>   proxy.sessionstorage
>       at Ext.Inventory.instantiateByAlias (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:13481)
>       at Object.createByAlias (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:5423)
>       at constructor.applyProxy (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:85923)
>       at constructor.setter [as setProxy] (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:9021)
>       at constructor. (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:9000)
>       at constructor.createImplicitModel (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:86564)
>       at constructor.applyFields (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:85893)
>       at constructor.setter [as setFields] (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:9021)
>       at Ext.Configurator.configure (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:9610)
>       at constructor.initConfig (app.js?_dc=1493205201288:11119)

I don't know whats going wrong because my app could recognize the session storage before the build, I tried to fix this bug in many ways, but is really hard because the app.js is compact.

My session storage code:

```
Ext.define('ES.store.Timeline', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  alias: 'store.timeline',
  storeId: 'timeline',
  fields: [{
    name: 'vid',
    type: 'int'
  }, {
    name: 'time',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'lat',
    type: 'float'
  }, {
    name: 'lng',
    type: 'float'
  }, {
    name: 'address',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'dir',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'vel',
    type: 'string'
  }, 'hidden'],
  pageSize: 500,
  autoSync: true,
  sorters: [{
    property: 'time',
    direction: 'DESC'
  }],
  data: {
    query: []
  },
  proxy: {
    type: 'sessionstorage',
    id: 'sessionTimeline'
  },
  filters: [{
    property: 'hidden',
    value: false
  }]
});
```

I'm calling the session store on a view:

```
...

    store: {
        type: 'timeline'
    },

...
```

How can I fix that bug? Thank you.

Comment: Which extjs version are u using ?

Comment: I'm using the 6.2.0 version

Comment: If you want to use json reader then you should use type as ajax.Just check this if its working properly

Comment: I'm not using json reader anymore, sorry, I forgot to remove this piece of code, on my new version I'm just adding the type

Comment: Check this link :http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy.html#cfg-reader . Here if you dont specify type it will always take json as reader type by default.

Comment: Try requiring the proxy explicitly in your store.

Comment: I tried but it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a requires on your store:

```
requires:[
    'Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage'
]
```

This tells ExtJS to load the file `data/proxy/SessionStorage.js` before construction of the store. Only when the `data/proxy/SessionStorage.js` file is loaded, the alias `proxy.sessionstorage` is registered, and thus, the proxy factory can correctly instantiate the proxy.